# What are the default usernames for Amazon EC2 Linux instances (for SSH, PuTTY, etc)?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am testing Linux instances on an EC2/AWS server (Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, Amazon Linux, etc.).

What are the default usernames, so I can connect via SSH?

Answer (score 3):

> For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is **ec2-user**.
>
> For a CentOS AMI, the user name is **centos**.
>
> For a Debian AMI, the user name is **admin**.
>
> For a Fedora AMI, the user name is **ec2-user** or **fedora**.
>
> For a RHEL AMI, the user name is **ec2-user** or **root**.
>
> For a SUSE AMI, the user name is **ec2-user** or **root**.
>
> For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is **ubuntu**.

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connection-prereqs.html

Answer (score 0):

The default username for Amazon Linux AMIs is root.

Answer (score -1):

you dont need an username to run instance on a putty , you just need insert key and public ip of taht in

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).